# Django: Form should edit only subset of many-to-many relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a template dedicated to only defining the m2m relationship between two models. There could be hundreds of m2m relations for each instance of the model.

```
models.py

class Treatment(models.Model):
category = CharField()
...

class Doctor(models.Model):
treatment = ManyToManyField(Treatment, blank=True)
```

In form I define a list of checkboxes for the m2m field

```
forms.py
class TreatCheckbox(forms.ModelForm):
    treatment = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Treatment.objects.all(),required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('treatment',)
```

--

```
views.py
def set_relations(request, pk):
    context={}
    context['doctor'] = Doctor.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.POST:
        form_treat = TreatCheckbox(request.POST, instance=context['doctor'])
        if form_treat.is_valid():

            #form_treat.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        form_treat = TreatCheckbox(instance = context['doctor'])
        form_treat.fields["treatment"].queryset = Treatment.objects.filter(category = 'dentistry')
```

The queryset assigned to the form reduces the options to a subset (category = 'dentistry').
If I use the form then only the selected relations in the form get saved but the data model looses all set relations that are not visible. It seems the save() load-replaces the m2m field.

I want only the shown relations to be changed by my view. How can I do that in a smart way?